# phonegap sqlite sync API with SQL Server 2005 / Oracle

Tags: cordova

We are planning to develop the ipad app using the phonegap API. Mobile Client (IPad) is going to use sqlite database. Remote db server will be SQL Server 2005 / Oracle. Can anyone suggest some bi-directional sync API can be used with this technical stack.

I have explored sybase mobile synchronization and microsoft sync. It seems sybase mobile synchronization is good option but not sure whether it is right choice for it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Brij

Comment: Oracle Mobile Server and Oracle Lite provides such synchronization but back end it should support only oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the sybase moblink is best solution for bi-direction synchronization. It has downside that only support ultralite as mobile client db.